# How to secure multiple connection strings in an application

Tags: c#, database, database-connection

I am creating windows forms application using C#. In my application 6 connection strings. These are loading data from 6 databases. I want to secure these connection strings using encryption and decryption. I find many examples on google  but these are only working for one connection string. How can I secure my 6 connection string?

Thanks

Comment: Would you please give more details on what your google examples looks like? Your question is about how to store, where to store or how to encrypt? By saying 'only working for one connection', you are saying you were able to encrypt one connection string separately and you want to have all of them together? Please give more details on what's on your mind or if you are open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy answer to your question. It really depends on how sensitive is your information and how much an attacker would want to get this information. The reason for this is simples: .NET applications can be decompiled easily (even the obfuscated ones).

That means if you store an encrypted something, you would need to store a encryption key anywhere. By using decompile, an attacker could take possession of your encryption key and, no matter how good is your algorithm, it is just a matter of time for decrypting something. So again, how sensitive is the information you are storing? Does it expires in some time? If not, how much protection you want to have?

There's no good way to store sensitive information in an application that does not change its encryption key over time.

But if you believe your information is not that sensitive and that you could use an "easy" encryption, you could try looking at [Rijndael](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael) encryption for .Net, and here it is a link for how to use this and some explanation about other encryption methods: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10154/NET-Encryption-Simplified

Symmetric algorithms provide a simple and good way of encryption for simple purpose encryption/decryption - let's say you want to store miles run on a health sports application - but they are not safe if you are storing credit cards numbers and passwords for databases with access to bank accounts, etc with encryptions that does not change over time. If your information is good enough, it is worth spending a whole year of computer processing to decrypt this information... so time is essential to your needs!

Hope this helps on your decision.

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer. but i am looking working exampple.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to encrypt sections of my web.config to protect both the <appSettings> and the <connectionStrings>.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

If you have a build server running you can have it encrypt the web.config so you can do local develop with plain text and have the encrypted versions on production machines.